# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] | Errors reading text from image with Python, OpenCV and OCR

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ocr

I'm having issues with this example code of how to read text from images using Python, OpenCV and OCR.

This code was built with python 2.7, and I'm using python 3.6 so maybe I'm missing some changes between these versions.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
src_path = "C:/Users/crist/Desktop/borrar/lectura/"
def get_string(img_path):
# Read image with opencv
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

# Convert to gray
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise
kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

# Write image after removed noise
cv2.imwrite(src_path + "removed_noise.png", img)

#  Apply threshold to get image with only black and white
#img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 31, 2)

# Write the image after apply opencv to do some ...
cv2.imwrite(src_path + "thres.png", img)

# Recognize text with tesseract for python
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src_path + "thres.png"))


#os.remove(temp)

return result


print ('--- Start recognize text from image ---')
print (get_string(src_path + "2.png"))

print ("------ Done -------")
```

---

Errors:

```
--- Start recognize text from image ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/crist/PycharmProjects/LectorTexto/lectorCapcha.py", line 40, in <module>
    print (get_string(src_path + "2.png"))
  File "C:/Users/crist/PycharmProjects/LectorTexto/lectorCapcha.py", line 31, in get_string
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src_path + "thres.png"))
  File "C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 122, in image_to_string
    config=config)
  File "C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 46, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 992, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The error seems to be on the `pytesseract.image_to_string()` line. Does the image you're trying to access actually exist at that point in time?

Comment: Your error seems to be "the system cannot find the file specified". That usually means the file doesn't exist or the path is wrong.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time! and yes it does, everything works fine util the actual text recognition, by that i mean.

Comment: 1) read original image with openCV
2)Convert it to gray scale
3) Erode, Dilate & Save
4)Black/White transform, & Save
Until there everything works fine!
I can go to the folder and see the new images with transformations.
I think if it actually was a path problem, it would´t be able to find the first image, dont know what else to do! Thanks!

Comment: i installed pytesseract through pip, is there anything else i missed? do i have to install tesseract and pytesseract?

Answer (score 0):

Import all the followings->>>>>>>

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import imutils
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string
```